# A very basic question about weighted data

Tags: syntax, random, distributions

I have a dataset in the form

```
{{A1,B1,C1,...},{A2,B2,C2,...},...}
```

and the weights in the form

```
{w1,w2,w3,...}
```

Having this information, I would like to produce fake data, i.e.

```
{{a1,b1,c1,...},{a2,b2,c2,...},...}
```

where a1,b1,c1,... are some random numbers generated using the weighted data. Could you please tell me how to do this?

As toy examples of the dataset and the weights, please find below:

```
n = 10^6;
Data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 10}];
WeightsValues = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n]; 
weightedData = WeightedData[Data, WeightsValues]
```

Comment: ```n = 10;
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
weightsValues = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
x = WeightedData[data, weightsValues]
Mean[x]```. If you want to retain the current structure then use `Flatten@Table...` for `WeightsValues`.

Comment: @Syed: thanks, I have corrected the code for WeightsValues.

Comment: ```n = 100;
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 10}];
weightsValues = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
x = WeightedData[data, weightsValues]
Mean[x]```. Sorry there was a typo for `data`. It is now an n x 10 array. `Random*` functions can created arrays, so there is no need for a `Table` with multiple indices. I cannot understand your question: Do you want to use this `weightedData` to generate random values? or such weights are already available?

Comment: @Syed: Thanks again! I want to use weighted data to generate random values.

Comment: e.g., ```data = {{A1, B1, C1}, {A2, B2, C2}};
w = {w1, w2, w3};
w # & /@ data``` gives `{{A1 w1, B1 w2, C1 w3}, {A2 w1, B2 w2, C2 w3}}`. Is this the correct structure? or should `w` have two entries only and `w1` multiplies first sublist of data and `w2` multiplies second sublist of data?

Comment: @Syed: assuming that we have some multi-dimensional distribution function distr[A,B,C,...], Y random numbers may be generated using RandomVariate[distr,Y]. The weighted data is what I have instead of distr. In the output, I would like to have something like RandomVariate, but with WeightedData "instead" of distr. WeightedData is actually something like distr, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
n = 10^3;
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 10}];
weightsValues = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
weightedData = WeightedData[data, weightsValues]
```

[image]

You can use [`EmpiricalDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html)+ [`RandomVariate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html):

```
edist = EmpiricalDistribution[weightedData];

sample = RandomVariate[edist, 3]
```

[image]